# Shared Network Works For Some But Not Others

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, internet, wireless-router

Ok, so my house has 4 devices that connect to the internet. 3 wireless and 1 wired. I own the wired device and 1 wireless device. The other 2 wireless devices can connect to the internet just fine but I can't connect to the internet with either my wired device or wireless device.

There is a catch. I can connect to the internet if I connect my wireless device using a wired connection (laptop), however it's very uncomfortable as the wires are fixed and it requires me to sit under the table.

I can access the GPON gateway using both devices so it's not a wire problem.

I have tried:

- Restart the computer
- Restart the router
- Clear cache.
- Switch to Google DNS

To no avail.

Any input is appreciated. This has been going on for months. My Internet provider is not helpful. They say because the other devices can connect to the internet just fine it's not their problem and won't help.

Comment: The 2 devices having issues, are they able to connect to the local network and it is just internet access they are lacking or are they completely unable to connect?

Answer (score 0):

any differences between your wired NIC config and wireless?

Are you getting an IP when connected via wiress? I would connect your wired connection, open CMD, do a IPCONFIG and look at the settings, then do the same when connected wirelessly. Might just be a good place to start.

Possibly IPv4/IPv6 issue? Any changes you made on the network adapters?

Comment: Welcome to Super User. This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.  Comments should also be used for helpful hints and diagnostic suggestions.  You can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://superuser.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://superuser.com/help/privileges/comment).